# PayPal PHP/HTML Security Issue

Tags: php, html, paypal

My PayPal amount can be edited on a webpage from inspect element. How can I make a piece of code not editable? or maybe hidden.

Comment: Relying on user input for setting the amount seems unwise.  Isn't the integration performed from server-side code?  Can't the server-side code determine the correct amount?

Comment: @David I am integrating server side code with a hidden PayPal html form. Except I don't know how to submit a form unless including the form to the HTML code. Can you suggest how I can go about this?

Comment: `"Can you suggest how I can go about this?"` - I suspect PayPal has lots of documentation and examples demonstrating how to integrate with their service.  If you have a specific question about some specific code you're writing, we can probably help with that.  But if you're just asking how to integrate with PayPal then the only reasonable answer is to check the vendor's documentation.

Comment: Here's how HTML and PHP work: HTML can be seen by all, meaning that all is editable. This is because HTML gives the layout of the webpage, so if you can see it, it is editable. PHP on the other hand is different. The user cannot see the PHP code, but what most often happens is PHP will create dynamic HTML based on how the user interacts with a webpage. PHP is on the server, but it generates HTML for the client that can be edited.

Comment: I'd start implementing a simpler form for which you keep some server side value before starting an actual PayPal integration. This question scares me a little.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid by your form. 
As mentioned in documentation, you must check variables (and so amount) sent by Paypal, when paypal validate the operation.